# How to creat a method to sort a 1D array of different customers type?

Tags: c#

```
public void sortByType(){}
```

what should i enter here if i have three types of customers different in the way they pay
I have a class customer that inhereted 3 other classes they have a name ,id ,balance and a name of the books array and the date of barrowing and returning how can i sort them by
 types??

```
class Book
{
    public string BName { get;set; }
    public string Day { get;set; }
    public string Month { get;set;} }
    public string Year { get;set;} }
    public override string ToString(){}
}
```

then I created an abstract class `Customer`

```
abstract class Customer
{
    protected string name;
    protected double balance;
    protected double ID_num;
    protected Book[] rental_books = new Book[3];
    public string Name { get { return name; } set { name = value; } }
    public double Balance { get { return balance; }  set { balance = value; } }
    public double ID_NUM { get { return ID_num; } set { ID_num = value; } }

    public override string ToString() {}
    public abstract void BarrowBook(string bn, string d, string m, string y);
    public abstract void ReturnBook(string bn, string d, string m, string y); 
    public abstract void AddToBalance(double sum); 
}
```

and inherted it to the other three child classes and add what I need to each method

```
class NormalCustomer : Customer{}

class MemberCustomer : Customer{}

class StudentCustomer : Customer{}
```

then I created a library class

```
class Library
{
    private Customer[] customers;
    private int MaxCust=0;
    private int count = 0;
    public Library(int MaxCust) { this.MaxCust = MaxCust; }  
    public void Add(Customer c) { customers[count++] = c; }
    public void ToString() {
    public void SortByBalance()
    {
        double hold;
        for (int i = 0; i < customers.Length - 1; i++)
            for (int k = 0; k < (customers.Length - 1) - i; k++)
            {
                if (customers[k].Balance > customers[k + 1].Balance)
                {
                    hold = customers[k].Balance;
                    customers[k].Balance = customers[k + 1].Balance;
                    customers[k + 1].Balance = hold; 
                }
            }
    }
}
```

so all i need now is the methode i mentioned above and how to creat it

Comment: this smells awfully like homework. Sorry mate but we're not here to do your homework. At most we can help you with that. So you need to show your attempts and describe what problems you have with your code.

Comment: I just need a way of sorting diffrent types in one array i don't need you to do the entire thing

Comment: it is a homework indeed . Try to edit your question or put some effort on it like adding some of what you tried ??

Comment: " i don't need you to do the entire thing " so why did you post these 10 requirements? Please post rather code. What exactly is your problem with sorting by type?

Comment: I posted the requirments so people could understand what i am doing with my code i just need away of sorting diffrent types off customers in a single one D array

Comment: how is **type** defined?

Comment: I have normal customer and a student customer and and member customer only diffrent by the way they pay to the library how can i sort them

Comment: Make those types implement an interface that has some sort of value property which can be used in sorting. That's basically it I guess, your whole homework that is intended to show you that interfaces are rather useful.

Comment: I guss i can do that but can i implement the same way on classes?

Comment: why don't you post your classes here. Cut them down to the necessary properties. Create a minimal example that can be copied and pasted into a new program and run there. Make an array filled with your customers, post it, so we can easily test it here.

Comment: I would but i am new to this so it may take a while

Comment: no problem. Welcome to StackOverflow :)

Comment: if you look at my answer, you can try to addapt the format to your question. 1) provide the classes. 2) create a sample input 3) provide your attempt if you have one 4) explain the problem 5) provide the expected output

Comment: Thanks man appreciate it :[]

Comment: the best way of saying thank you on StackOverflow is to mark the answer that helped you as accepted. If you don't know how to do it [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) may help. Happy coding

Comment: one last advise: you really should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. please finish editing your post and provide the necessary information. Then I can vote to reopen your question. It just has to have a valid format to survive on this forum and also help others witha  similar problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's take your classes

```
public class Customer { ... }

public class NormalCustomer : Customer{}

public class MemberCustomer : Customer{}

public class StudentCustomer : Customer{}
```

Providing an array which contains all the children in a mixed order:

```
Customer [] array = new Customer[]
{
    new StudentCustomer(),
    new MemberCustomer(),
    new NormalCustomer(),
    new MemberCustomer(),
    new StudentCustomer(),
    new StudentCustomer(),
    new NormalCustomer(),       
};
```

You can use the method: [OfType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.8) to extract the individual types:

```
var children_1 = array.OfType<NormalCustomer>();
var children_2 = array.OfType<MemberCustomer>();
var children_3 = array.OfType<StudentCustomer>();
```

Now you simply need to concatenate them into a single collection using the [Concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=netframework-4.8) method. It expects that the second collection contains the same type of elements so you need to cast it temporarily to the parent type:

```
Customer [] sorted children_1.Cast<Customer>().Concat(children_2).Concat(children_3).ToArray();
```

Comment: Ok this is very useful for me but let's say just for example i desided to make my customer class abstract  because there is a methode that behave differently in each child i can't instintate any object form it what can you advice me to do

Comment: @Yaman "what can you advice me to do " I don't see any problem in what you wrote so far... If you decided to specify the type by inheritance then it makes perfect sense not to allow the base class to be instantiated. Does the implementation of `BarrowBook` differ in the different customer-child classes? Or is `AddToBalance` the only method that is different in all 3 child classes?

Comment: Yes th BarrowBook implemnt is different in each child class that's why it's abstract

Comment: i'm a little lost on how can i compaine all of these classe in the main() like how i'm supposed to sort them and how to enter the values

Comment: @Yaman you would need a collection of `Customer`s like I showed in my answer. a `List<Customer>` would be good since it can be extended. You can sort them the way I showed you. But to enter the values, you would need to program a user interface that asks for user input.

Comment: @Yaman did you manage to solve your problem? or are you still stuck somewhere?

Comment: yes my problem is solved i have used the GetType() methode and typeof to solve it sorry for taking so long to answe